# Clojure test namespace convention

Tags: clojure

I have traditionally used the same folder structure for production and test code as demonstrated below:

```
src/myproject/core.clj
test/myproject/core_test.clj
```

For test files I have added `_test` in the filename.

I recently noticed that several projects follow this structure (this is also what Leiningen generates by default):

```
src/myproject/core.clj
test/myproject/test/core.clj
```

Is there a convention regarding this or some clear advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: As long as everybody working on the project follows the same convention, and it's easy to find the test ns for a given production ns, I'd say it's a matter of personal preference. This isn't Java where the packages need to line up for protected/default access.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe this is just convention - I don't think there is any technical advantage either way.

I personally prefer the first version for entirely non-technical reasons:

- It seems redundant to have two "test" directories in the path.
- It can cause confusion to have the test .clj files with the same names as the main .clj files
- Sometimes you want to create tests that don't perfectly line up with specific namespaces, e.g. `full_system_test.clj` for end-to-end testing
- It's easier to pattern-match on all the `*_test.clj` files

Also worth noting that the [Maven standard directory layout convention](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) is also used in quite a few Clojure projects (this can be handy if you build polyglot projects that also contain Java source code):

```
src/main/clojure/myproject/core.clj
src/test/clojure/myproject/core_test.clj
src/main/resources/....
src/test/resources/....
```

Comment: +1 to the Maven layout. It's likely to come in handy on any moderately complicated project.

Comment: Also, it can get confusing/annoying having two files named core.clj. Especially when you're digging through stack trackes.

Comment: Bill makes a very good point. Even in production code, we try to name things like com.xyz.xyz-core - it also helps when you have lots of editor windows open.